# Why is span defined as the linear combination with *finite* terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, topological-vector-spaces, motivation

I understand that, for a vector space $V$ with scalar field $K$, the linear span of a family of vectors $S\subseteq V$ is usually defined as $$ \mathrm{sp}(S):=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i \mid k\in \mathbb{N},  a_i \in K, v_i\in S\right\} $$ In words: the span is the set of finite linear combinations of the vectors in $S$.

My question is about the motivation for defining the span to be a **finite** linear combination. Is there some uncomfortable conclusions  that would result from using a definition like $$ \mathrm{sp}(S):= \left\{ \sum_{v\in S} a_v v \mid a_v \in K \right\}$$
I suspect that this has something to do with preserving important structures of $S$ in the span of $S$ (perhaps topological structures?), but I have no concrete examples.

Comment: Maybe because an infinite sum should be defined as the limit of finite partial sums, and the order of terms matters

Comment: One would need to specify a topology. There can be topologies for which an infinite sum converges, and other topologies for which the same sum does not converge. You might look into Schauder bases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

Comment: An infinite sum doesn't make any sense without the term of convergence of a sequence. If you have a normed space then you can define a limit of a sequence, and this gives a meaning to convergence of an infinite series. But in an arbitrary vector space, how would you define an infinite sum?

Comment: Worth noting that the "span" for vector spaces is a special case of "substructure generated by a subset" in algebra in general, i.e. the smallest substructure containing a given subset, i.e. the intersection of all substructures containing a given set. You can equivalently define a subgroup, or subring, or subalgebra generated by a subset. What matters is that any subspace of your vector space must contain all those _finite_ linear combinations, and then it is easy to see that it doesn't need to contain anything else!

Comment: @VincenzoTibullo, Nick, and Mark That clears it up for me. The definition using the infinite sum is ill defined without the presence of a topology and convergence. Once an underlying topology is specified, is it preferable to allow convergent infinite sums into the definition of the span or do we still stick to finite sums?

Comment: Note also the scalar field $K$ does not need to be $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb C$ - think also of finite fields where, surely, the only topology that makes any sense would be discrete.

Comment: @MeirShachar Span by definition always contains finite linear combinations. But we may also consider infinite linear combinations, it's just not called the span. For example, infinite linear combinations are extremely important in Hilbert spaces. (Fourier series are such infinite combinations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind: the axioms of a vector space provide a *binary* sum operation, and so you get linear combinations of the form $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 = \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i v_i
$$
By applying the associative law of addition you get a well-defined trinary or 3-fold sum operation, and so you get linear combinations of the form
$$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 = \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i v_i
$$
Continuing by induction on $n$ (and applying the associative law at each step of the induction) you get a well-defined $n$-fold sum operation for any natural number $n$, and so you get linear combinations of the form
$$a_1 v_2 + a_2 v_2 + ... + a_n v_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i
$$
But there's nothing in the axioms of a vector space which lets you jump to infinite sums.

As the commenters have pointed out, you can get infinite sums by adding extra structure such as a norm which gives you a concept of convergence.

But norms are not unique, and unless you are lucky, different choices of a norm give you different concepts of convergence, and so you either have to *choose* a norm, or you're out of luck.

Granted, there are lots of situations in mathematics where a natural choice of norm presents itself. Hilbert spaces come to mind as an example of this phenomenon, and there are lots of useful infinite sums in a Hilbert space.

If you are very very lucky then the concept of convergence is independent of the norm. Actually you don't have to be all that lucky, because for any finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ the concept of convergence (the topology) is *indeed* independent of the norm; that covers lots of useful vector spaces.

But in general different norms give different concepts of convergence, and you should not expect infinite linear combinations to make sense independent of the choice of norm.

Comment: One thing that confused me a lot was not knowing the difference between a Hamel basis and a Schauder basis. I think the explicit naming to distinguish the two goes a long way.

Comment: Yeah, those names post-date me. I think of them as a "basis" and a "hilbert space basis", myself.